# How to create an automated and unattended Clonezilla Restore solution with dhcp

Tags: restore, clonezilla

I can not get the DHCP to work when I boot up the usb drive or the auto script to work. I know I am close but I could not find the usb self help page on clonezilla's site. the link is broken.

https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/05_Preseed_options_to_do_job_after_booting

I have followed this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65848953/how-to-create-an-automated-and-unattended-clonezilla-restore-solution) and changed the code where I believe I am supposed to.

I changed ocs_prerun="mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt" ocs_prerun1="mount --bind /mnt/images /home/partimag/"

to this ocs_prerun3="sshfs $SSH_ACCOUNT@$SSH_SRV:"$SSHFS_DIR" /home/partimag/" (Replace $SSH_ACCOUNT, $SSH_SRV, and $SSHFS_DIR with appropriate values, like: "sshfs chopin@192.168.100.254:/home/chopin /home/partimag". You can get more info about sshfs by reading its manual).

Here is my final code.

menuentry "Flysoft RESTORE" {
search --set -f /live/vmlinuz
$linux_cmd /live/vmlinuz boot=live union=overlay username=user config components quiet noswap edd=on nomodeset enforcing=0 noprompt ocs_prerun3="sshfs jsmith@10.16.10.157:/home/jsmith /home/images/TCImages" /home/images/TCImages/" ocs_live_run="ocs-sr -g auto -e1 auto -e2 -r -j2 -k -scr -batch -p reboot restoredisk ask_user sda" keyboard-layouts="de" ocs_live_batch="yes" locales=de_DE.UTF-8 vga=788 ip= nosplash net.ifnames=0 splash i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=1
$initrd_cmd /live/initrd.img
}

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.